# Impact of Moon's gravitational pull on Earth

Tags: classical-mechanics, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

What speed does the Moon's gravitational pull impart to Earth?

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE. It's unclear what you're asking, could you clarify? Are you asking if the Earth moves because of the moon?

Comment: Unclear question. How did you think of the earth getting speed from moon's Gravitational pull?

Comment: This question could be good if the OP responds and edits correspondingly. I hope there are no blatant duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you have to understand is that the gravitational force imparts an acceleration, and not a speed, to the object it is acting upon. This acceleration is related to the force by: $$F=ma=-\frac{GMm}{r^2}\hat{r}$$

(where $\hat{r}$ indicates that the force is along the line joining the center of mass of the two bodies)

Second, it is wrong to say that the moon orbits around the Earth. Both the moon and the Earth orbit around their center of mass. The distance of the center of mass from the center of the Earth is given by: $$\frac{M_{moon}d_{moon}}{M_{Earth}+M_{moon}}$$

Which is approximately: $ 4500 \ km$ (and hence lies inside the Earth)

So, it appears that the moon orbits around the Earth but both the moon and the Earth orbit around this point.

To find the Earth's velocity (of orbit), we know that the centripetal force acting on the Earth is provided by the moon and is $\frac{GM_{Earth}M_{Moon}}{r^2}$. ($r$ is the Earth-Moon distance)

Therefore: $$\frac{M_{Earth}v^2}{r_{cm}}=\frac{GM_{Earth}M_{Moon}}{r^2}$$

Hence, $v$ is:

$$\sqrt{\frac{M_{moon} G r_{cm} }{r^2}}$$

Which is around a $12 \ m \ s^{-1}$. (which is almost unnoticeable compared to the moon's $1000 \ m \ s^{-1}$ orbital velocity.)

Hope this answers your question!